# How to select and map 1:N relationships with IDataReader and SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

For a very simple example, A Company has man users. I have two tables, Company and User. The User table has a foreign key CompanyId. Say I have to fill a list of Companies and all their Users, how would I map this with a datareader?

Do I need multiple select statements? One to get all companies needed and then another to get all users within the selected companies? Pseudo code below.

```
 select companies;
 Loop through all companies returned and create a list of companyids for where in.
 select users where in (companyid list created above)
 attach users to selected companies
```

Logically, what would be the best approach to accomplish this task.

Comment: It would be best to join the results on the SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use an ORM (which would make this much easier), then you want to do a JOIN statement, and then perhaps use a `Dictionary` to store the primary key of each company as the key of the dictionary, and then a `Company` instance as the value for the dictionary, which will contain a collection of `User` instances.

E.g.

```
SELECT [column list] FROM Companies c INNER JOIN Users u ON u.CompanyId = c.Id;
```

Comment: Then when mapping the companies, just check to make sure it's not building a company for all the results that hold the same values. Company 1 has 10 users, it's going to build the same company 10 times without manually checking?

Comment: Yes exactly, that's why a dictionary may be useful to track which company instances have already been created.